# Algorithms not being numbered correctly

Tags: algorithms

I am trying to include some algorithms in an IEEE paper and the algorithms are not being numbered properly. I'm new to Latex and have never used it before. I want to number it as Algorithm 1 and Algorithm 2 and so on. Not Algorithm .1 and Algorithm .2

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
    \KwIn{ Image}
    \KwOut{Detected object (Wave/Spiral)} 
\begin{enumerate}
\item Detect all possible contours in the image
\item Calculate the total area of the uploaded image
\item For each contour:
\begin{itemize}
    \item Calculate the area of the contour
    \item If the area of the contour is more than 80\% of the total area of the image, then discard it and move to the next contour
    \item If the area of the contour is less than 80\% of the total area of the image, then check if the center of the contour is in the center of the image
    \begin{itemize}
    \item If not, discard the contour and move to the next contour
    \item If yes, calculate the aspect ratio of the contour
            \begin{itemize}
            \item If the aspect ratio is more than 1.7, feed the object detected within the contour into the wave classifier model
            \item If the aspect ratio is less than or equal to 1.7, feed the object detected within the contour into the spiral classifier model
            \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\item Return the detected object
\end{enumerate}
\caption{Spiral or Wave Algorithm}
 \label{c3:algosow}
\end{algorithm}
```

[image: As you can see it is being pictured wrong.]

Comment: ". 1" indicates that it is part of a subsection that has no parent section (or chapter-section), I guess.

Comment: So what am I supposed to do about it? All the algorithms are under the section \section{Algorithms}.

Comment: Please don't show only a code snippet, but show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) that could be used to reproduce the issue without guessing. You should start with `\documentclass` add all *needed* package and preamble code (but try to really only show the *needed* parts), have a `\begin{document}` and some body to produce the shown screenshot, and end with `\end{document}`. This would really help us, to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `algosection` option.

```latex
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,algosection]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Spiral or Wave Algorithm}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Spiral or Wave Algorithm}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]